# Warum heisst es "keine zusätzlichen Massnahmen", aber "[mehrere] zusätzliche Massnahmen"?

Tags: grammar-identification, weak-declension

> Es sind keine zusätzlichen Massnahmen erforderlich.

> Es sind zusätzliche Massnahmen erforderlich.

Beide Sätze sind vom Sprachgefühl her korrekt, aber ich komme einfach nicht darauf, aufgrund welcher Regel "zusätzlich" einmal auf "-en" und einmal auf "-e" endet. Kann es sein, dass der der erste Fall bestimmt ist und der zweite unbestimmt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nein, unbestimmt sind beide. *Kein* ist aber ein Artikelwort, und damit bekommt es die starke Endung, und das Adjektiv *zusätzlich* bekommt nur noch eine schwache Endung.

Nur wenn das unbestimmte Artikelwort in der Grundform steht, wie zum Beispiel in *kein zusätzlicher Aufpreis*, bekommt stattdessen das Adjektiv die starke Endung.